# Why does the following c code not work?

Tags: c, string, char, printf, scanf

I am trying to convert the character of which a user types in to its character code.

```
int main(){
    char converter;
    scanf("enter a character: %c", &converter);
    printf("your character code is %d", converter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't prompt with `scanf()`.  You just read data with it.

Comment: how changing scanf(...) to printf("enter a character: ");scanf("%c", &converter);?

Comment: What is the question here? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the key code for each character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char converter;
    printf("enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &converter);
    printf("your character code is %d", (int)converter);
    return 0;

}
```

Also, each corresponding code can be found here:
http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html